# Root Test: What happens if $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} =1$?

Tags: calculus, analysis

Root Test: For a series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, let $\ell = \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.  Series is convergent if $\ell <1$ and divergent  if $\ell \geq 1$. I have the question about $\ell =1$. Some of the standard calculus book mention that the root test fails for $\ell =1 $ and some other mention it is divergent in this case. Your thought please.

My thought: $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} \geq 1$ imples that 
$|a_n| \geq 1$ for sufficiently large $n$ which means $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} |a_n|\geq 1 \neq 0$. Therefore divergent by the Divergence test.

Comment: You can't say anything. It can converge or diverge ! For example $\sum_{n}1^n$ diverge, but $\sum_{n}\frac{1}{n^2}$ converge

Comment: Please, provide examples.

Comment: I gave you example :)

Comment: No text says $l=1$ implies divergence.

Comment: @zhw: Look at the book Introduction to Analysis, by Edward Gaughan, page no. 185.

Comment: I don't have that book, but I tend to doubt it says what you claim. Can anyone check this? Anyway, the examples you've been given here show the $l=1$ case is indeterminate.

Comment: I checked 5th edition of the book, and the relevant theorem says: If, for infinitely many $n$, $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\geq1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges. This not only is a true statement, but also assumes something fairly different from $\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}\to1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq1} \frac{1}{n}$ and $\displaystyle\sum_{n\geq2} \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$ behave differently, the former is divergent, the latter is convergent, in both cases
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sqrt[n]{|a_n|} =1.
$$

Comment: Please prove a proof of your second example.

Comment: It's easier to look at $\sum 1/n^2$ in place of your second series.

Comment: @Mr.MBB. Just apply https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test. and you obtain $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$, which converges

Answer (score 3):

If $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ then the series diverges but $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges to $1$.

If $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ then the series converges but $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges to $1$.